# I can't get the shade editor to use nodes in 2.8

Tags: shaders

So I have used 2.83.0 for a while now, but this is the first time I have used the Shade editor, since before 2.8. The thing is I tell the editor to use nodes, and design said nodes, but when the shader is displayed in the viewport it only renders the setting used without nodes. I tried switching from eevee to Cycles and no change has occurred. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This could be GPU related - Try updating your drivers.

Comment: Actually I updated my Graphics cards driver less then a week ago, however this is the first time I have encountered the issue. Could it because its not completely compatible with the new version of the driver?

Comment: I also updated to the newest version of blender, and it's still happening.

Comment: It's possible. You could try a rollback to the previous version (if you are able) and see if that fixes anything, however this sometimes requires _all traces_ of other driver versions to be removed from the system (using something such as DDU) to work properly. Only do it if you're comfortable with doing so.

Comment: Also, what GPU do you have, may I ask? If it's an older card (or a brand spanking new one), it could be a compatibility issue.